# Redis tcp-backlog

Tags: redis

Someone know how to solve this redis problem on startup?

**redis_version:2.4.17**

It comes on /etc/init.d/redis_4986 start 
redis_4986.conf tcp-backlog is like default:

**tcp-backlog 511**

```
Starting Redis server...

*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 54
>>> 'tcp-backlog 511'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using a version of Redis which does not support yet this configuration parameter. For instance, a Redis 2.6 or lower binary with a 2.8 or better configuration file.

Comment: OK... so i have just to comment this directive or there is some work around?

Comment: Yes, you can comment it - the default value should be fine for most purpose. But you may have other parameters like this - perhaps you should retrieve an example of config file suitable for your version of redis, and start again from this point.

Comment: Note that Redis 2.4 is now extremely old. The recommended version is Redis 2.8.