# Redis can't persist on Centos 7

Tags: redis, centos

Here's my situation ; I'm currently building VMs on Amazon and trying to install and run Redis on them. Everything is fine with Ubuntu ; however, I have some issues with Centos 7.
The installation is fine, but when I try to run Redis I get this error :

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR *** Reading the configuration file, at line 554
'aof-load-truncated yes' Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

So, this line is the problem. I saw some people having the same kind of error, it seems to be related to Redis version. Yet I took the last .conf file from the official depo, for the 2.8.x version ... Anyway, If I comment this line, Redis starts. But, it won't persist data (which is a bit problematic) ! I get this message whenever. I set a value with redis-cli :

```
(error) MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error.
```

I understand there's something wrong with the persistence, but I can't find a solution for this.

I tried to run Redis on Centos 6.5 and I got the same error than this person :  [Redis tcp-backlog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993159/redis-tcp-backlog)

Voila. I'm beginning with Redis, I may therefore be missing something pretty simple.If anyone has an idea, I would gladly hear it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar error

> (error) MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error.

What worked for me was solution suggested on the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots).

Basically due to low memory there was error during BGSAVE and then entire persistence would be stopped. So following settings worked for me.

1. set vm.overcommit_memory = 1
2. config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no

Also read Redis persistence [docs](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) and blog [post](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html).

Comment: Thank your very much ! I solved the problem by resizing my VM's memory, but your solution worked also with the previous configuration. I'm gonna read the blog post which seems to be pretty interesting.