# Redis can't start due to tcp-backlog

Tags: macos, redis

I am using the osx and trying to install redis through brew

```
brew install redis
==> Downloading http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-2.8.17.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/redis-2.8.17.tar.gz
==> make -C /private/tmp/redis-WEL8AT/redis-2.8.17/src CC=clang
==> Caveats
To have launchd start redis at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/redis/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load redis now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
==> Summary
```

At last I have installed redis, but when I run it in the way of

```
redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

there is error message,

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 54
>>> 'tcp-backlog 511'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

I learned from [Redis tcp-backlog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993159/redis-tcp-backlog) to uncomment the redis.conf in that line.
but still more errors on other lines come again.
How do I solve it ?

Comment: Just use a configuration file which corresponds to the actual redis version. Check the redis-server you launch does correspond to the version you think you have installed.

Comment: the current redis config is automatically generated after the installation of redis from brew. so normally it should correspond to the right version of redis, isn't it

Answer (score 15):

Check if you have installed redis twice. I my case I had another redis installation from anaconda with version 2.6.9:

```
$ which redis-server
/Users/<username>/anaconda/bin/redis-server
$ redis-server -v
Redis server v=2.6.9 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64
```

Homebrew instead will install the redis-server to a different place:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/redis-server -v
Redis server v=3.0.1 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64 build=bf58331b4c8133f5
```

So to start the homebrew version with the homebrew config file do

```
$ /usr/local/bin/redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

Comment: Thanks @asmaier, you really help me a lot.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem due to a config file left over from previous redis versions. Uninstalling all redis versions and reinstalling the latest worked (also, don't forget to update brew before installing redis):

```
brew uninstall redis --force
brew update
brew install redis
```

You should now be able to start it.

Comment: Thanks，SBBS. I still got the issue saying: *** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 90
>>> 'tcp-keepalive 0'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments

Comment: @user824624, uninstalling redis using `brew uninstall redis --force` should remove the config file. If it doesn't, them remove it manually after uninstalling by running `$ rm /usr/local/etc/redis.conf`. Then install redis and it should work. And don't forget to update brew prior installing redis.